# how would i reduce the amount of if statemnts in my code?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make an application for my FlipperZero in C, an auto clicker of sorts. But I have the issue of way too much lag going on when changing the "selected" variable. I don't know how I would fix this.

To clarify a bit, I'm not trying to do math; these are key codes for key inputs.

```
if (selected == 0) {
            Key_code = 0x04;
          }
          if (selected == 1) {
            Key_code = 0x05;
          }
          if (selected == 2) {
            Key_code = 0x06;
          }
          if (selected == 3) {
            Key_code = 0x07;
          }
          if (selected == 4) {
            Key_code = 0x08;
          }
          if (selected == 5) {
            Key_code = 0x09;
          }
          if (selected == 6) {
            Key_code = 0x0a;
          }
          if (selected == 7) {
            Key_code = 0x0b;
          }
          if (selected == 8) {
            Key_code = 0x0c;
          }
          if (selected == 9) {
            Key_code = 0x0d;
          }
          if (selected == 10) {
            Key_code = 0x0e;
          }
          if (selected == 11) {
            Key_code = 0x0f;
          }
          if (selected == 12) {
            Key_code = 0x10;
          }
          if (selected == 13) {
            Key_code = 0x11;
          }
          if (selected == 14) {
            Key_code = 0x12;
          }
          if (selected == 15) {
            Key_code = 0x13;
          }
          if (selected == 16) {
            Key_code = 0x14;
          }
          if (selected == 17) {
            Key_code = 0x15;
          }
          if (selected == 18) {
            Key_code = 0x16;
          }
          if (selected == 19) {
            Key_code = 0x17;
          }
          if (selected == 20) {
            Key_code = 0x18;
          }
          if (selected == 21) {
            Key_code = 0x19;
          }
          if (selected == 22) {
            Key_code = 0x1a;
          }
          if (selected == 23) {
            Key_code = 0x1b;
          }
          if (selected == 24) {
            Key_code = 0x1c;
          }
          if (selected == 25) {
            Key_code = 0x1d;
          }
```

I have a.h file with a bunch of variables for each letter, but I don't know how to use it in this situation.

I'm just lost when it comes to this. I don't know how I would even begin to optimize it.

In case it isn't obvious, I'm new to C, and I'm only learning it to make flipper applications.

Comment: Isn't `key_code = selected + 4`?

Comment: _"But I have the issue of way too much lag going on"_ - what do you mean by "way too much lag"?

Comment: Ok there are many ways to improve this as it betrays you really could benefit from a tutorial walk through of the language. Using `else if` after the first `if` is an obvious first improvement that will prevent checking additional conditions after you get to the right one. However a `case` statement is better. And the comment above may be better still in this particular case (have not checked if it works). In short, do a tutorial.

Comment: "" - what do you mean by "way too much lag"?" Basically, it takes way to long for inputs to go through, in my previous attempts before i added the if statements i had no such issues. Im using a flipperzero so im very limited on ram

Comment: your code hardly damage your app performance. so you may find the problem elsewhere

Comment: "But this is really a code review question, which doesn't belong on this site" im a noob so i dont know what sites i should ask what questions on,  what site should i use for code review?

Comment: If nothing else, learn how to use `else`. Every `if` after the first one should be preceded by `else`.

Answer (score 5):

If your code actually continues like this, wouldn't it be easier to just do this:

```
int getKey(int selected) {
    return selected + 4;
}
```

If not, you can optimize this code by using an array or a switch statement, which will make it more efficient and easier to manage. I'll show you how to do this using an array.

First, you can create an array to map the `selected` variable to the `Key_code` values:

```
// Define an array to map selected values to Key_code values
uint8_t keyCodes[] = {
    0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d,
    0x0e, 0x0f, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17,
    0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d
};

// Check if selected is within a valid range
if (selected >= 0 && selected <= 25) {
    Key_code = keyCodes[selected];
} else {
    // Handle the case where selected is out of range
    // You can set a default value or take some other action.
}
```

With this code, you create an array `keyCodes` that maps each value of `selected` to the corresponding `Key_code`. Then, you check if `selected` is within the valid range before accessing the array. If `selected` is out of range, you can handle it as needed.

Comment: Good answer. UV'ing... But, 1st sol'n (`selected+4`) doesn't embody the range checking provided by either OP's exact match or your 2nd solution. Jus' sayin'... :-)

Comment: Thanks, i would have never thought of this

Comment: @Fe2O3 I agree, it’s just that in the 2nd solution there'll be a garbage value when trying to get the value out of range of the array, which can be regarded as an error. In the 1st case, the normal value will return. If desired, it will not be difficult to adapt 1st code for the ragne checking ;)

Comment: This is so trivial. How come none of my answers have every received 5 upvotes?